# How can i convert from Rapid Miner exampleset into weka instances?

Tags: machine-learning, rapidminer, text-classification

I need some functionality to be used from weka and some functionality to be used from rapidminer. How can i convert into rapid miner exampleset into weka instances perform some operations and then convert back into weka instances ?

I found a class on internet mentioned as "WekaTools"  but it does not exist in rapidminer(5.3.013)

Can any one tell me where this functionality is moved in rapid miner 5.3.013? or how can i convert from Rapid miner example set into weka Instances ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download and install the Weka extension which is available from the RapidMiner Marketplace.

From the GUI, Help, Updates and extensions and then search for Weka.